# Qustion with contexts in chapter 3.3 book k&r

Tags: c

In book is given to me function ----

```
/* binsearch find x in v[0] <= v[1] <= ... <= v[n-1] */
int bin( int x, int v[] , int n)
{
     int low, high , mid;

     low = 0;
     high = n -1;
     while( low <= high) {
            printf("LOL\n");
            mid = (low+high)/2;
            if( x < v[mid])
            high = mid + 1;
            else if ( x> v[mid])
            low = mid + 1;
            else return mid;

            }   
return -1;    
}
```

This is text for function:
Binary search first compares the input value x to the middle element of the array v. If x is less
than the middle value, searching focuses on the lower half of the table, otherwise on the upper
half. In either case, the next step is to compare x to the middle element of the selected half.
This process of dividing the range in two continues until the value is found or the range is
empty.

Why is it that when I put in `int v[4] nexts elements = { 2,3,4,5}` and `for x = 2` the loop goes on forever?

Is this their mistake?

Answer (score 2):

Your code has a typo.
Instead of

```
        if( x < v[mid])
        high = mid + 1;
```

there shall be

```
        if( x < v[mid])
        high = mid - 1;
```

Also it would be better if the function would be declared as

```
int bin( int x, const int v[] , int n);
```

because the algorithm does not change the array itself and could be applied to constant arrays.

Take into account that there is standard C function `bsearch` declared in header `<stdlib.h>`

Comment: thank for respo. , i saw that mistake in if statment but that like is in the book

Comment: @lotoflaugh Many books contain typos.:)

Answer (score 0):

You have made a slight error in the program... in the line 10 it should be

```
if(x<v[mid])
{
   high=mid-1;
}
```

...
rest is fine...thats why it was resulting in a forever loop